# Creating a room by reading from a file (for a game)

Tags: java, file, 2d

Basically i have to make a game and i need to create the room by reading from a file, this one:

```
#
# 0 D room0.txt 0
# 1 E room1.txt 0
#
WWWW0WWWWW
W        W
W        W
W        W
W        W
W      W W
W      W W
W      W W
W      W 1
WWWWWWWWWW
```

The "#" means that i can skip those lines(they're just for information) and the "W" are the places i need to put a Wall, the numbers are for the doors and the blank spaces are the floor.

I figured the best way to create the room is to create a method that receives a file and reads it and put its "information" into a String[10][10], and then create another method(or just do it in my Main) that receives the String[10][10] created and creates the room(adds the images to the room), but i am having some difficulties reading the file so if you guys could help me with that part i would be thankful.

The error that i get when i run the program is on this line:

if(r[x][y].equals("W"))

if you guys need another class, an image of what the game should look like or something else that i forgot to show please let me know and thanks for the help.

```
public void generateRoom(File file){     
    if(file.exists()){
        Scanner sc = null;     
        String[][] r = new String[10][];
        int row = 0;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file); 
            String line = sc.nextLine(); 
            while(sc.hasNextLine() && row < 10){
                if(line.startsWith("#"))
                    sc.nextLine();
                else{
                    String[] s0 = line.split("");
                    if(s0.length==10){
                        r[row]=s0;

                    row++;
                }         
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){    
         for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
             if(r[x][y].equals("W"))
                   tiles.add(new Wall(new Position(x,y)));      
             if(r[x][y].equals("1") || r[x][y].equals("2"))
                   tiles.add(new Door(new Position(x,y)));
             if(r[x][y].equals("0")){
                 tiles.add(new Door(new Position(x,y)));
                 hero.setPosition(new Position(x,y));
                 tiles.add(hero);
             }
             else tiles.add(new Floor(new Position(x,y)));
             gui.newImages(tiles);
             gui.update();
         }
        }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Ficheiro "+file.getAbsolutePath()+
                    " não existe. ");           }
        finally{
            if(sc!=null)sc.close();
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Ficheiro "+file.getAbsolutePath()+
                " nã£o existe. ");
```

}

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Don't use split with an empty delimiter, use .getChars()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never reassigning `line`.

This:

```
if(line.startsWith("#"))
    sc.nextLine();
```

should read

```
if(line.startsWith("#"))
    line = sc.nextLine();
```

But your procedure is overly complicated. You can read the file and generate the room in a single pass. Consider the following version of your procedure:

```
public static void generateRoom(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (file.exists()) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        int row = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if (line.startsWith("#"))
                continue;
            for (int col = 0; col < line.length(); col++) {
                switch (line.charAt(col)) {
                case 'W':
                    System.out.println("new wall @" + row + '/' + col);
                    break;
                case '0':
                    System.out.println("hero @" + row + '/' + col);
                    // fall-through
                case '1':
                case '2':
                    System.out.println("new door @" + row + '/' + col);
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    System.out.println("new floor tile @" + row + '/' + col);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("invalid char @" + row + '/' + col);
                }
            }
            row++;
        }
        sc.close();
    } else
        System.out.println("Ficheiro " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " nã£o existe.");
}
```

It avoids the temporary string array altogether. Additionally, you can use a `switch` statement for decoding the characters in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line;

while (sc.hasNextLine() && row < 10) {
    line = sc.nextLine();
    if (line.startsWith("#")) {
        line = sc.nextLine();
    } else {
        String[] s0 = line.split("");       
        if (s0.length == 10) {
            r[row] = s0;
            row++;
        }
    }}
```

Not advancing line.